# Unity Direct Compute: Setting a struct of arrays

Tags: unity, compute-shader

The [NVIDIA Direct Compute programming guide](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2010/presentations/S12312-DirectCompute-Pre-Conference-Tutorial.pdf) lists some best practices for memory management on the GPU. One tip they give on page 8 ("Structured Buffers") is to use a 'structure of arrays' (SOA) layout rather than the typical 'array of structures' (AOS) one:

```
struct Particle {     
    float4 position;    
    float4 velocity;
}; 
RWStructuredBuffer<Particle> particles;
```

vs

```
struct Particles {     
    RWStructuredBuffer<float4> position;    
    RWStructuredBuffer<float4> velocity;
}; 
Particles particles;
```

(At least, as far as I understand)

AOS layout seems to be the most popular (maybe even only) way to manage lists of stuff in the compute shader.

I haven't found a way to implement SOA from the CPU side, Unity's [`ComputeShader.cs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ComputeShader.html) doesn't have a set struct function or similar. Does Unity expose a way to set SOA structs from the CPU side at all?